# Can i use code from projects in code share in my apps on app exchange

Tags: force.com, appexchange

i know the projects that are on code share in developer force are open source but just want to make sure i don't run into problems by confirming from you guys in the community.

Comment: which projects are you talking about? As far as I understand, there is no way one can get your code(if it's a managed app), even if someone gets hand on your code, recognizing that it's copied is even more difficult. If you are not millionaire, no one will spend money to sue you & get bad press in return. It should be safe.

Comment: Some interesting insights here. @Ganesh do you feel if someone fails to get your code, or fails to recognize the copy, or fails to spend money to sue you, that this  makes it OK? I do appreciate the ambiguity of the situation if a license is not present.

Comment: @user320 I understand what you are taking about. as mentioned in question we are speaking about Open Source Projects. But unfortunately whole software industry is dominated by companies which are either patent trolls or are willing to go lengths to avoid competition. So even if we are coping code from Open Source Projects, bits & pieces of the code might have been patented without knowledge of original project developers. My point is-coping from Open Source Project is also potentially dangerous if you work with big product companies-think Oracle Vs Google case about coping 4 lines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whilst all the projects on Code Share are Open Source, Code Share does not enforce the use of a particular Open Source license. This is covered on the [Creating a Code Share Project](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_a_Code_Share_Project) page.

> Your source code typically has a license attached to it as well, which describe the terms under which it may be used. Many of the salesforce.com contributed projects, such as TwitterForce, Force.com for Facebook and Force.com for Google App Engine, use the New BSD License.

The rules governing re-use are going to to depend on the specific license that covers the project you are interested in using. Generally projects will have a **license.txt** file in their root directory which will identify which license the code is under. If in doubt you can always try and contact the project owner to establish which license is in use, or to ask for their consent to re-use the code within a commercial product.

It's worth noting that if a license is not provided, then the default copyright laws apply, this assertion is backed up by [github's documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/open-source-licensing) on licensing.

> Generally speaking, the absence of a license means that the default copyright laws apply. This means that you retain all rights to your source code and that nobody else may reproduce, distribute, or create derivative works from your work.

For more information on Open Source licensing take a look at the [Open Source Initiative](http://opensource.org/licenses) website which covers a lot of the most popular ones, Wikipedia also has a useful [comparison table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_free_and_open-source_software_licenses) which might help you out.